# I can't find the T_comp instruction in TIA Portal v16

Tags: comparison, comparator, siemens, tia-portal

or what to do instead of T_COMP? (LAD)

T_COMP compares two tags with a time data type. For LAD and FBD, the
comparison function is displayed with an EN/ENO box. For STL, it is a block call.
To compare time data types for SCL tags, use the comparison expression (see
Chapter 13.3.1 “Execution of “simple” comparison function” on page 570). The tags
to be compared are present at parameters IN1 and IN2. The parameter OUT provides the comparison result: Signal state “1” (TRUE) if the comparison is fulfilled
and signal state “0” (FALSE) if it is not fulfilled.

[t_comp pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRLbo.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple comparisons in LAD too.

[image: Time comparison LAD pic]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question was "I can't find the T_comp instruction in TIA Portal v16, or what to do instead of T_COMP? (LAD)".  He did answer the second part of the question, with an example that is unambiguous for users of the software.  Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

T_COMP is available in extended instructions for LAD and FBD.  I believe that is what you are asking.

[image]